# What upgrades affect car performance?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

What upgrades actually affect car performance? I can see changes of stats when applying engine, brakes, turbo, transmission, etc. But, there are some upgrades that are not really clear such as wings, hood, skirt or tire customization.

Do they change performance at all? Will it be able to stick to the road more with better tire? Will it be able to have faster RPMs with a better cooling system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [IGN Wiki](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Customizing_Your_Ride), the following upgrades have an effect on the car's performance:

- Armour (*+20-100% defence*)
- Brakes (*increase breaking*)
- Engine (*increases acceleration*)
- Transmission (*increases acceleration*)
- Turbo (*greatly increases acceleration*)

The following have no effect on the car's performance:

- Bumper
- Chassis
- Exhaust
- Fender
- Grille
- Hood
- Horn
- Lights
- Plate
- Roll Cage
- Roof
- Side Step
- Skirts
- Spoiler
- Suspension
- Tailgate
- Wheels
- Window

The following are online-only upgrades:

- Explosives
- Tracker *GPS Tracker in your car*
- Full Coverage *Insures your vehicle if destroyed*

Comment: Spoilers have an effect, if the bar at the bottom doesn't lie. I play it on PC btw.

Comment: Well, it turned out that suspension actually is not purely cosmetic. Even iFruit tells that. It makes the car slide less on the road (and off-road).

Answer (score 4):

After doing some testing, I have noticed a difference between off-road tires and high-end tires, both on the street and off-road. I can tell a difference in cornering (as well as traction over bumpy terrain) when I alter the car's suspension.

Therefore I'm quite sure that it is wrong to say that wheels or suspension have no effect on car performance.

However, I don't know to what extent the other changes, if any, have upon car performance.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm which upgrades actually affect your car, as for which ones don't, I'll tell you what I always tell everyone, if it makes you feel like you're going faster then maybe it is, but ultimately the best testing is the testing you do yourself and you should take a lot of rumours with a pinch of salt.

Armour is essential in a race because avoiding damage keeps your car fast and competitive throughout the length of the race.

Brakes are important for extra stopping power unless you are driving something with brakes that lock up a lot Ie; Brawler or Slamvan, in these cases consider using the 1st brake upgrade instead of the maximum upgrade as it makes it easier to feather the brake pedal (so to speak) and maintain a decent amount of traction under braking.

Engine, Transmission & Turbo upgrades not only increase the acceleration of your vehicle but also the vehicle's ability to reach it's maximum speed, never trust the in game stats because they are deceptive and don't tell the whole story.

Spoilers, yes they do add a decent amount of traction to your car, making cornering smoother and helping to battle snap oversteer, but more than that, increasing the traction stat helps apply braking force to the road under you and the same with acceleration forces, try it for yourself.

Suspension upgrades are harder to explain, it is up to you to determine which cars need suspension upgrades and which don't, if you are a 'curb booster' (I'll explain that one later) then stock suspension will probably benefit you more than a lowered car possibly could, but cars that tend to roll over in some corners might be better off with a lower centre of gravity so consider buying an upgrade.

Wheels, as a general rule a tyre with a chunkier sidewall (Offroad) will absorb bumps and curbs better than a smaller profile sidewall (High end) this is also useful for 'curb boosting' and is why you might encounter many of the racing crews using off roads as their main hot lapping tyre choice, and don't forget bulletproofs, they don't just deflect bullets, they also can't be punctured from burnouts.

Curb Boosting is an exploit within the game whereby you can mount and dismount curbs during a race for a slight boost in your engine revs and ultimately making you move faster in a straight line vs people who aren't using the curbs, this works differently depending on your car choice, for example the Zentorno will gain a larger boost from curbs than the Osiris. Curb boosting can be useful but also a problem for other racers on the track, weaving back and forth trying to grab curbs can cause you to take out other racers and knock down a lot of poles and debris in the middle of the race track. I would suggest avoiding over use of Curb boosting but instead try to use it mainly for 1 player hot lapping scenarios where you are trying to set a world record lap for example.

That concludes my life story, hope this helps some people

Answer (score 1):

Well the graphs in game show bo effect but if you log in ifruit app, i actually have two identical cars for different characters at different progressions. IE have more armor and tires and whatnot. It shows my handling inproved and also my weight increased im guessing for my armor and my suspension. So i'm guessing there might be something to it

Answer (score 0):

I found that when you change your wheels (the rim) to a non-stock one, this do affect the performance, so do the exhaust. Although the stat in Los Santos Customs doesn't show, it (the stats) shows in the iFruit App, which you can download it with your real physical world smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall with the other updates the game did have affect with how much quicker your car goes with certain amount of armor.  Because I raced someone with the same t20 and I had 60% armor and he had 100% armor but I was a lot quicker then him, after the next update or latest update, they changed it now, armor doesn't have any affect no matter how much armor you put on or not.  I remember very well and I believed I took a video of it too, but I'm not sure I uploaded it yet.  If someone can try out the other patches of this game you'll see they changed it.

Answer (score -1):

- Roof plates lower your centre of gravity for better handling.
- Spoilers increase downforce. Try using a super car with one then
  without - the spoiler version will have better traction, specially at high speeds and be faster.
- Suspension definitely affects handling.

  The only thing I don't know is whether custom hoods and grilles affect performance. In game they affect engine cooling according to description but I've never been worried about my virtual car overheating.

Does anyone know if it has any actual effect on performance? You must have done more research than type and post please